# Need to get usernames and passwords from database.yml file and pass into method in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rake, pg

Currently, I am using the pg gem in my rails rake task which is perfect for what I want to do. I create a variable pg_conn and pass in the connection details to the PGconn.connect method. I just don't want to change this rake task everytime the database usernames/ passwords change. How can I pass in the login details from my yaml file to the pg_conn command. Take a look at my code below:

```
namespace :update_table do
  task :import => :environment do

$pg_conn = PGconn.connect(host =  "samsi-postgres-90s", port = 6433, options = '', tty ='',      dbname = "installs", login = "reports_m", password = "password")

my_query = "select * from all_tables"

   conn.query(my_query) do |raw_row|
     puts raw_row
   end

  end
end
```

Ideally, I would like to pass a hash of credential details to the pg_conn connection variable like so:

```
$pg_conn = PGconn.connect(yamlfile[:host], yamlfile[:port], '', '', yamlfile[:database], yamlfile[:username], yamlfile[:password])
```

How can I do this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Rails3, you can use [Rails.configuration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application/Configuration.html) in your rake task:

```
  config   = Rails.configuration.database_configuration
  host     = config[Rails.env]["host"]
  database = config[Rails.env]["database"]
  username = config[Rails.env]["username"]
  password = config[Rails.env]["password"]
```

Just make sure you inherit the environment in your rake task such as

```
task :users => :environment do
```

Answer (score 1):

Given this Yaml file:

```
:host: samsi-postgres-90s
:port: 6433
:database: installs
:username: reports_m
:password: password
```

you can load it this way:

```
require 'yaml'
yamlfile = YAML.load(open('your_file_path'))
```

then you can write:

```
yamlfile[:host] # => "samsi-postgres-90s"
```

etc.

Comment: and? How do I access the the :host, :port, :database?

Comment: I have many environments in the file. I run the rake command like this: RAILS_ENV='production' rake update_levels_table:import.. But the yamlfile hash has everything.. All environments!

Comment: Sorry I've missed it's a Rails application, if it's Rails 3 see @mguymon's answer.